# Doctrine 2 Multiple select elements, aliases, date_format

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i'm new with doctrine and want to make a query on my db using it

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(created_at), '%m-%Y') AS 'date', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) AS 'value'
FROM users
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE(created_at)), MONTH(DATE(created_at))
```

i read some documentation but still have few questions

how to i select multiple elements; give aliases to my selected elements, do a left join. Are WEEK() MONTH() and YEAR() functions avaible ? does DATE_FORMAT (from mysql) is avaible ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use the query builder (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

Considering date, you can use symfony datetime objects and format them.
For left join the leftJoin method can be used (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

```
<?php
// $qb instanceof QueryBuilder

$qb->select('u as aliasName')      //see for alias
   ->from('User', 'u')
   ->leftJoin('u', 'phonenumbers', 'p', 'u.id = p.user_id')  //see     for left join
   ->where('u.id = ?1')
   ->addwhere(u.date < :date)
   ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC')
   ->setParameter('date', $symfonyDateTime->format('Y-m-d')); //see for date
```

Instead of QueryBuilder, you can also try DQL (http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p
    FROM AppBundle:Product p
    WHERE p.price > :price
    ORDER BY p.price ASC'
)
->setParameter('price', 19.99);

$products = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could install [doctrine extensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) in order to use functions like:

`DATE, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK` and many more.

Example:

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      ....
      orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                dql:
                  datetime_functions: 
                    DATE_FORMAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DATE_FORMAT
```

Then you can really easy add alias like this:

`DATE_FORMAT(s.createdAt,'%Y-%m-01') as date`